# Android-TableLayout Height issue

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table but because of the content of the cells their height is different.

[image]

(Sorry for the bad pic)

And this looks so bad.

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/row7_2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"/>
```

Since I'm already using `layout_weight` this can't be my option to solve this problem.So any help will be appreciated.How can I fix the heights of the cells no matter their content is?

Answer (score 0):

As you use wrap content larger text get large space

```
android:layout_height="20 dp"
```

here 20dp is just for example.you can use larger size for matching up your cell.